# Copying char data between structs

Tags: c++

I'm having a data abort exception in my code. It is very likely I am doing a very bad operation with chars. This code seems to work, but I wonder if it is actually invalid. The question is, what happens if you copy the data of one struct to another with char arrays involved. How is the data copied?

I have two functions, one which will purposefully leak, because I want to also know what happens if the struct created with `new` lives on purposefully, but the struct whose data it copied goes out of scope.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "string.h"

typedef struct {
    char name[12];
    char stupid[12];
    int hello;
} tFile;

void CopyFileAndDelete(tFile *file1){
    tFile *file2 = new tFile;
    *file2 = *file1;
    std::cout << file2->name << std::endl;
    delete file2;
}

void CopyFileAndLeak(tFile *file1){
    tFile *file2 = new tFile;
    *file2 = *file1;
    std::cout << file2->name << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    tFile file1;
    memset(&file1, 0, sizeof file1);
    file1.hello = 22;
    snprintf(file1.name, 12, "%s", "hellogoodfriendhwoareyou");
    snprintf(file1.stupid, 12, "%s", "greate");
    CopyFileAndDelete(&file1);

    CopyFileAndLeak(&file1);
}
```

Comment: What is "a data abort exception"? Show us exactly what you see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than this code being generally unsafe and more C than C++, it's correct (other than the leak.) There is no way this can produce an exception (unless `new` throws due to memory allocation failure.)

Arrays inside structs will be copied as you'd expect. The compiler will generally do a `memcpy()` to copy them (or a special `memcpy`-like built-in to optimize the copy operation.)

This isn't code you should write though. Use `std::string` instead. Don't use `new` and `delete`, use value types instead. If you really need to allocate, use `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` to do it.

Don't write code like this in C++ :-)

Comment: Our code base is a wild mix of legacy C and C++, and I often have no choice. This is not actual code but just a tiny app to demonstrate the question.